# How to set outcome of XUnit test

Tags: testing, automated-tests, nunit, xunit

Can you manually set outcome of test using XUnit? In one of my test I have to fulfill prerequisite and if it fails I need to set outcome of test to *inconclusive*. In NUnit you can set outcome by `Assert.Inconclusive()`, `Assert.Fail()`, etc. Am I able to do something similar with XUnit? Is there some best practice how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way of doing what you want in xUnit. See https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons.html for more information.

However Assert.Fail("This test is failing") can be replicated using Assert.True(false, "This test is failing").

The closest equivalent of Assert.Inconclusive in XUnit would be the use of the Skip attribute. But as far as I can see, there is no way to invoke this part way through a method, like you can with NUnit's Assert.Inconclusive.

Someone did write an Assert.Skip method for v1.9 here: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/v1/samples/AssertExamples/DynamicSkipExample.cs, however it no longer compiles in v.2.2.0. Actually the xUnit authors seem to be antagonistic to inconclusive tests (https://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9691).

Comment: FYI, the sample has been updated for newer versions of xunit: [https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/DynamicSkipExample](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/master/DynamicSkipExample).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Assume.That in your munitions test method it won't work while setup but you will to use that in test method.

Comment: I can't find way to use `Assume.That` intellisense offers only `Assert`. I am using xunit 2.2.0 on NetCore 1.1. Can there be problem?

Comment: It might be that the answer is confusing NUnit with XUnit, and thinking that [`Assume.That`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/Assumptions.html) is available in XUnit.